# Setting the value of properties via reflection

Tags: c#, .net, reflection

I am working on an application in which I have to parse an XML file. Nodes of the XML file corresponds to an object. I have to populate the properties of the objects at run time. The code below queries the metadata of property and sets its value. Is there a better way to do it or is there a better way to map the elements of an XML to an object?

```
public static void SetPropertyValue(object obj, string propertyName, object propertyValue)
    {
        if (obj == null || string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(propertyName))
        {
            return;
        }

        Type objectType = obj.GetType();

        PropertyInfo propertyDetail = GetPropertyInfo(objectType, propertyName);

        if (propertyDetail != null && propertyDetail.CanWrite)
        {
            Type propertyType = propertyDetail.PropertyType;

            Type dataType = propertyType;

            // Check for nullable types
            if (propertyType.IsGenericType && propertyType.GetGenericTypeDefinition() == typeof(Nullable<>))
            {
                // Check for null or empty string value.
                if (propertyValue == null || string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(propertyValue.ToString()))
                {
                    propertyDetail.SetValue(obj, null);
                    return;
                }
                else
                {
                    dataType = propertyType.GetGenericArguments()[0];
                }
            }

            if (dataType.Equals(typeof(int)))
            {
                propertyValue = Convert.ToInt32(propertyValue);
            }

            if (dataType.Equals(typeof(long)))
            {
                propertyValue = Convert.ToInt64(propertyValue);
            }

            if (dataType.Equals(typeof(short)))
            {
                propertyValue = Convert.ToInt16(propertyValue);
            }

            if (dataType.Equals(typeof(bool)))
            {
                string stringPropertyValue = propertyValue.ToString();
                if (stringPropertyValue.Equals(Boolean.FalseString, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase) || stringPropertyValue.Equals("0"))
                {
                    propertyValue = false;
                }
                else
                {
                    if (stringPropertyValue.Equals(Boolean.TrueString, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase) || stringPropertyValue.Equals("1"))
                    {
                        propertyValue = true;
                    }
                }
            }

            if (dataType.Equals(typeof(float)))
            {
                propertyValue = Convert.ToSingle(propertyValue);
            }

            if (dataType.Equals(typeof(double)))
            {
                propertyValue = Convert.ToDouble(propertyValue);
            }

            if (dataType.Equals(typeof(decimal)))
            {
                propertyValue = Convert.ToDecimal(propertyValue);
            }

            if (dataType.Equals(typeof(byte)))
            {
                propertyValue = Convert.ToByte(propertyValue);
            }

            if (dataType.Equals(typeof(string)))
            {
                propertyValue = Convert.ToString(propertyValue);
            }

            if (dataType.Equals(typeof(char)))
            {
                propertyValue = Convert.ToChar(propertyValue);
            }

            if (dataType.Equals(typeof(DateTime)))
            {
                propertyValue = DateTime.ParseExact(propertyValue.ToString(), "yyyy-MM-dd", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
            }

            propertyDetail.SetValue(obj, propertyValue);

        }
    }
```

Comment: In order to tell whether there is a better way of translating your xml into an object we need to see the xml structure and the target object.

Comment: Have you considered using plain Jane XML serialization?

Comment: I agree with @RubberDuck , I would attempt to obtain a Schema for this file and use the XSD.exe to generate a class to which the xml could be serialized against.  Its direct and no need for reflection.

Comment: Thanks @RubberDuck .. I am trying to upgrade a legacy application (something that is > 20 years old) and the information that I have about the schema is limited. However it makes to create the schema based on the sample xml files that I have and update it as more information is available.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use reflection to parse some common `.Net` types:

```
public static object Parse(Type type, string str)
{
    try
    {
        var parse = type.GetMethod("Parse", new[] {typeof(string)});
        if (parse == null) throw new NotSupportedException();
        return parse.Invoke(null, new object[] { str });
    }
    //or don't catch
    catch (Exception)
    {
        return null;
    }
}
```

It will basically allow you to replace this code:

```
        if (dataType.Equals(typeof(float)))
        {
            propertyValue = Convert.ToSingle(propertyValue);
        }

        if (dataType.Equals(typeof(double)))
        {
            propertyValue = Convert.ToDouble(propertyValue);
        }

        if (dataType.Equals(typeof(decimal)))
        {
            propertyValue = Convert.ToDecimal(propertyValue);
        }

        if (dataType.Equals(typeof(byte)))
        {
            propertyValue = Convert.ToByte(propertyValue);
        }

        if (dataType.Equals(typeof(string)))
        {
            propertyValue = Convert.ToString(propertyValue);
        }

        if (dataType.Equals(typeof(char)))
        {
            propertyValue = Convert.ToChar(propertyValue);
        }

        if (dataType.Equals(typeof(int)))
        {
            propertyValue = Convert.ToInt32(propertyValue);
        }

        if (dataType.Equals(typeof(long)))
        {
            propertyValue = Convert.ToInt64(propertyValue);
        }

        if (dataType.Equals(typeof(short)))
        {
            propertyValue = Convert.ToInt16(propertyValue);
        }
```

with this line:

```
propertyValue = Parse(dataType, propertyValue.ToString());
```

It will work for every other class, that has `public static void Parse(string)` method declared (most standart value types do). You can add `Parse(string)` method to your own classes, to make them support this kind of deserialization. You can also modify the above code to use `Parse(string, IFormatProvider)` instead, to avoid parsing issues related to different decimal separators in different cultures.

Answer (score 3):

You can use Convert.ChangeType method for removing some conditionals. An example below :

```
class Person
{
    public int Name {get;set;}
    public bool BoolVar {get;set;}
    public float FloatVar { get; set; }
    public DateTime DateVar {get;set;}
}

class MainClass
{
    public static void Main (string[] args)
    {
        Person p = new Person ();

        SetPropertyValue (p, "BoolVar", true);
        SetPropertyValue (p, "FloatVar", 11.5);
        SetPropertyValue (p, "DateVar", "2015-05-01");

        Console.WriteLine (p.BoolVar);
        Console.WriteLine (p.FloatVar);
        Console.WriteLine (p.DateVar);

    }

    public static void SetPropertyValue(object obj, string propertyName, object propertyValue)
    {
        if (obj == null || string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(propertyName))
        {
            return;
        }

        Type objectType = obj.GetType();

        PropertyInfo propertyDetail = objectType.GetProperty(propertyName);


        if (propertyDetail != null && propertyDetail.CanWrite)
        {
            Type propertyType = propertyDetail.PropertyType;

            Type dataType = propertyType;

            // Check for nullable types
            if (propertyType.IsGenericType && propertyType.GetGenericTypeDefinition() == typeof(Nullable<>))
            {
                // Check for null or empty string value.
                if (propertyValue == null || string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(propertyValue.ToString()))
                {
                    propertyDetail.SetValue(obj, null);
                    return;
                }
                else
                {
                    dataType = propertyType.GetGenericArguments()[0];
                }
            }

            propertyValue = Convert.ChangeType (propertyValue, propertyType);

            propertyDetail.SetValue(obj, propertyValue);

        }
    }
}
```

If the XML format is yours and you be able to replace it, it's better to use xml serialization.

Comment: Thanks Niels. Unfortunately I am still trying to fully understand the schema. I had the function Convert.ChangeType in mind but I thought the exception handling associated with this function will become a little messy so I didn't follow this path.